# Optimized functions to compute projection of a point on a line?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, 3d, geometry

Consider the following problem:
[image: projection]

My question is the following: how to optimize the following independent functions:

```
// Computation of the coordinates of P
inline std::array<double, 3> P(const std::array<double, 3>& A, 
                               const std::array<double, 3>& B,
                               const std::array<double, 3>& M)
{
    // The most inefficient version in the world (to be verified)
    std::array<double, 3> AB = {B[0]-A[0], B[1]-A[1], B[2]-A[2]};
    std::array<double, 3> AM = {M[0]-A[0], M[1]-A[1], M[2]-A[2]};
    double norm = std::sqrt(AB[0]*AB[0]+AB[1]*AB[1]+AB[2]*AB[2]);
    double dot = AB[0]*AM[0]+AB[1]*AM[1]+AB[2]*AM[2];
    double d1 = dot/norm;
    std::array<double, 3> AP = {AB[0]/d1, AB[1]/d1, AB[2]/d1};
    std::array<double, 3> P = {AP[0]-A[0], AP[1]-A[1], AP[2]-A[2]};
    return P;
}

// Computation of the distance d0
inline double d0(const std::array<double, 3>& A, 
                 const std::array<double, 3>& B,
                 const std::array<double, 3>& M)
{
    // The most inefficient version in the world (to be verified)
    std::array<double, 3> AB = {B[0]-A[0], B[1]-A[1], B[2]-A[2]};
    std::array<double, 3> AM = {M[0]-A[0], M[1]-A[1], M[2]-A[2]};
    double norm = std::sqrt(AB[0]*AB[0]+AB[1]*AB[1]+AB[2]*AB[2]);
    double dot = AB[0]*AM[0]+AB[1]*AM[1]+AB[2]*AM[2];
    double d1 = dot/norm;
    std::array<double, 3> AP = {AB[0]/d1, AB[1]/d1, AB[2]/d1};
    std::array<double, 3> P = {AP[0]-A[0], AP[1]-A[1], AP[2]-A[2]};
    std::array<double, 3> MP = {P[0]-M[0], P[1]-M[1], P[2]-M[2]};
    double d0 = std::sqrt(MP[0]*MP[0]+MP[1]*MP[1]+MP[2]*MP[2]);
    return d0;
}

// Computation of the distance d1
inline double d1(const std::array<double, 3>& A, 
                 const std::array<double, 3>& B,
                 const std::array<double, 3>& M)
{
    // The most inefficient version in the world (to be verified)
    std::array<double, 3> AB = {B[0]-A[0], B[1]-A[1], B[2]-A[2]};
    std::array<double, 3> AM = {M[0]-A[0], M[1]-A[1], M[2]-A[2]};
    double norm = std::sqrt(AB[0]*AB[0]+AB[1]*AB[1]+AB[2]*AB[2]);
    double dot = AB[0]*AM[0]+AB[1]*AM[1]+AB[2]*AM[2];
    double d1 = dot/norm;
}

// Computation of the distance d2
inline double d2(const std::array<double, 3>& A, 
                 const std::array<double, 3>& B,
                 const std::array<double, 3>& M)
{
    // The most inefficient version in the world (to be verified)
    std::array<double, 3> AB = {B[0]-A[0], B[1]-A[1], B[2]-A[2]};
    std::array<double, 3> AM = {M[0]-A[0], M[1]-A[1], M[2]-A[2]};
    double norm = std::sqrt(AB[0]*AB[0]+AB[1]*AB[1]+AB[2]*AB[2]);
    double dot = AB[0]*AM[0]+AB[1]*AM[1]+AB[2]*AM[2];
    double d1 = dot/norm;
    double d2 = norm-d1;
    return d2;
}
```

So that each function will be as much optimized as possible ? (I will execute these functions billion times).

Comment: You should implement them first and profile the code then ask how to optimize the trouble spots.

Comment: I have added the most inefficient versions in the world (calculations still need to be checked)

Comment: You don't know if it works and you already want to improve it? Anyway http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Optimise in what way? Replacing the `array<double,3>` with a 3D vector class with the appropriate operators (+,-,Dot,Cross,etc) would make the code so much more readable and less prone to errors, thus, optimising maintenance costs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From algorithm point of view, you can calculate projection of vector to another vector not using SQRT call

the pseudocode from here 
http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/elements/line/projections/

```
// projection of vector v1 onto v2
inline vector3 projection( const vector3& v1, const vector3& v2 ) {
    float v2_ls = v2.len_squared();
        return v2 * ( dot( v2, v1 )/v2_ls );

}
```

where dot() is a dot product of two vectors and len_squared is the dot product of vector with self.

NOTE: Try to pre calculate inverse of v2_ls before main loop, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to compute all requested quantities in a single go.

Let `P = A + t . AB` the vector equation giving the position of `P`. Express that `MP` and `AB` are orthogonal: `MP . AB = 0 = (MA + t . AB) . AB`, which yields `t= - (MA . AB) / AB^2`, and `P`.

`t` is the ratio `AP / AB`, hence `d1 = t . |AB|`. Similarly, `d2 = (1 - t) . |AB|`. `d0` is obtained from Pythagoras, `d0^2 = MA^2 - d1^2`, or by direct computation of `|MP|`.

Accounting: compute `MA` (3 add), `AB` (3 add), `AB^2` (2 add, 3 mul), `MA.AB` (2 add, 3 mul), `t` (1 div), `P` (3 add, 3 mul), `|AB|` (1 sqrt), `d1` (1 mul), `d2` (1 add, 1 mul), `MA^2` (2 add, 3 mul), `d0` (1 add, 1 mul, 1 sqrt).

Total 17 add, 15 mul, 1 div, 2 sqrt.

Answer (score 0):

If you want portable code, so no processor specific features are used, I'd suggest the following:-

1) As I mentioned in my comment above, create a 3D vector class, it will just make it a lot easier to write the code (optimise development time)

2) Create an intersection class that uses lazy evaluation to get P, d0 and d1, like this:-

```
class Intersection
{
public: 
  Intersection (A, B, M) { store A, B, M; constants_calculated = false }
  Point GetP () { CalculateConstants; Return P; }
  double GetD0 () { CalculateConstants; Return D0; }
  double GetD1 () { CalculateConstants; Return D1; }
private:
  CalculateConstants ()
  {
    if (!constants_calculate)
    {
      calculate and store common expressions required for P, d0 and d1
      constants_calculate = true
    }
  }
```

3) Don't call it a billion times. Not doing something is infinitely quicker. Why does it need to be called so often? Is there a way to do the same thing with fewer calls to find P, d0 and d1?

If you can use processor specific features, then you could look into doing things like using SIMD, but that may require dropping the precision from double to float.

Answer (score -1):

The following is a C++implementation of point-to-line projection calculation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
// the point
double x0 = 1.0, y0 = 1.0;
// the line equation
double A = 1.0, B = 1.0, C = 0.0;
// calc point to line distance
double dist = fabs(A * x0 + B * y0 + C) / sqrt(A * A + B * B);
// calc project point coord
double x1 = x0 - dist * A / sqrt(A * A + B * B);
double y1 = y0 - dist * B / sqrt(A * A + B * B);
// result
cout << "project point：(" << x1 << ", " << y1 << ")" << endl;
return 0;
}
```